# Cannot get rid of error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I am pulling data from four different tables on the same database, and am attempting to merge these data into a single HTML object. The problem is I keep getting the "open DataReader" exception above.

Things I have tried:

- Closing the reader with `reader.Close()` after each `if(reader.HasRows)` block
- Declaring the `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` locally to the `try/catch`
- Adding a `finally` statement at the end of each `try/catch` that closes the reader (this one complained that the `reader` variable hasn't been initialized)

None of the above work. All of the solutions I have found say to use `MultipleActiveResultSets`, but I don't actually want multiple result sets.

What are best practices to use in a situation like this? Declare four different reader variables with four different names, reader1, reader2, etc?

**Edit**

Here's a sanitized and shortened version of what I'm doing

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["database"].ToString();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd;
SqlDataReader reader;
SqlConnection conn;

using (conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table-one]", conn);
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // Get a temporary copy of the data in a data table
            dt.Load(reader);

            // Do database things on table-one
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception caught
        ThrowException(ex);
    }

    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table-two] WHERE UserID = @uID", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("uID", User_ID));
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // Get a temporary copy of the data in a data table
            dt.Load(reader);

            // Do database things on table-two
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception caught
        ThrowException(ex);
    }
```

Comment: Actually the error says that the DataReader "must be closed", so "closing the reader with reader.Close()" should work. Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/08/20/there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-command-which-must-be-closed-first-explained.aspx and see if your code is similar to it. Also your code will help to understand the issue

Comment: I would think so, too, but I'm still getting the exception. It's bizarre. Should I close the connection after each table read, and reopen it for the next one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table-one]", conn);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        // Get a temporary copy of the data in a data table
        dt.Load(reader);

        // Do database things on table-one
    }
```

try:

```
using (cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table-one]", conn))
{
     using (reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
         if (reader.HasRows)
         {
             // Get a temporary copy of the data in a data table
             dt.Load(reader);
         }
     }
}

// Do database things on table-one
```

I.e. close/dispose each reader before doing any more database stuff.

Comment: Unless you must keep a resource for longer than a routine executes you should always wrap such resources in using statements to ensure their cleanup.  Doing his version wouldn't have even occurred to me.  However, AFIAK SqlCommands aren't resources that need cleaning up.

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate connection to the database for each command/reader you are using. Please post the code which has the problem, it will make it easier to give a more specific answer.

If you are combining data from four tables, why not do that in one SQL statement? You will then only need one connection and one command.

Although you say

> I don't actually want multiple result sets

running four separate queries will give four separate results.

**EDIT**

You have declared the `SQLSqlCommand` outside your `try/catch` blocks and it does not appear to be closed/cleaned up. Move the declaration in to the block where it's used:

```
//SqlCommand cmd;       <<-- remove
//SqlDataReader reader; <<-- remove
SqlConnection conn;

using (conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        // Add the variable declarations here
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table-one]", conn);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // Get a temporary copy of the data in a data table
            dt.Load(reader);

            // Do database things on table-one
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Exception caught
        ThrowException(ex);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand what MARS does; I was under the impression that it allowed multiple result sets to be open at once. I'm writing the data to arrays and then going to the next table.

Comment: Updated answer for you to try. If you declare the `cmd` and `reader` objects in each block they will be closed when you have finished with each table. Then close the connection when you are done.

Comment: Your edit is one of the things I have tried: "Declaring the SqlCommand and SqlDataReader locally to the try/catch". I'm going crazy or something, because I was sure that a locally declared variable would be trashed after the closing brace.

Answer (score 1):

You do not close SqlDataReader. Always call Close when done reading or execute the whole thing in a Using statement.

Example

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//SqlCommand cmd;
//SqlDataReader reader;
//SqlConnection conn;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd;

    conn.Open();

    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table-one]", conn);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // Get a temporary copy of the data in a data table
            dt.Load(reader);

            // Do database things on table-one
        }
    } 

    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table-two] WHERE UserID = @uID", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("uID", User_ID));
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            // Get a temporary copy of the data in a data table
            dt.Load(reader);

            // Do database things on table-two
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Calling `reader.Close();` is bullet point 1 that I have tried

Comment: Please see the update code, it should work. I prefer to use a using-block.

Answer (score 1):

In general there are two reasons for this error (at least I haven't noticed any other so far):

The first is not properly closing a Reader. This can be resolved pretty easily with using:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "select getdate()";
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //do your stuff...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second reason is concurrency. If you want to read additional data, from the same thread or another thread, like the following:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = "select columns from accounts";
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //fetch additional data for each record.
                using (SqlCommand innerCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    innerCommand.CommandText = "select * from sales where account_id = @account_id";
                    using (SqlDataReader innerReader = innerCommand.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (innerReader.Read())
                        {
                            //read sales data    
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to enable MultipleActiveResultSets. This way SqlServer allows several open dataReader on a single connection.
From your code it seems that you're running into the first issue...

Answer (score -1):

Here you are calling second data reader without closing your first data reader object .use this for close relevant transactions belongs to your relevant data reader

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [table-one]", conn);
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        // Get a temporary copy of the data in a data table
        dt.Load(reader);

        // Do database things on table-one
    }
    reader.Close();  
}
```

Comment: This question was answered and accepted a year ago, and your answer only parrots the other responses. Further, your solution is bullet point 1 of things I'd already tried. Did you fully read the question and other answers before adding your own?